# BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Filesystem::assertExists

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am working on tests for a laravel app using phpunit I am trying to run the following to make sure the file exists.

```
Storage::disk('local')->assertExists("mib_players.csv");
```

But when i run test I get the following error.

```
BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Filesystem::assertExists
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: assertExists is not a function returned from disk

Comment: I found this assertExists on the following page https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/how-to-check-if-uploaded-file-exists-in-storage-if-name-was-hashed?page=0 is their another way to test that the file exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of this wrong. First, you're calling `assertExists()` on your `Storage` object. You need to call the assert function on your `TestCase` object instead. Furthermore, there is no `assertExists()`, only `assertFileExists()` and `assertDirectoryExists()`, but those assert if a file in a specific path exists.

What you should do is have a method in your `Storage` object that check that certain file exists within it, like this:

```
public function fileExists($path) {
   // check if file exists
   return true; // or false
}
```

and then assert that the function returns true

```
$this->assertTrue(Storage::disk('local')->fileExists("mib_players.csv"));
```

I don't know the specifics of your class, but alternatively you could have a method that returns the path of the `Storage`, then you could do this:

```
$this->assertFileExists(Storage::disk("local")->getPath()."mib_players.csv");
```

[Reference](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertFileExists)

Comment: Thanks for your help I was able to check for the file like this.   $this->assertFileExists(storage_path('app/flatfiles/mlb_players.csv'));

Comment: I'm glad you could fix it! I just now realized I somehow missed you were using Laravel. The `assertExists()` method is definitely in the `FilesystemAdapter` class, so try updating your Laravel version (`composer update`), maybe you have an older version! [See here](https://github.com/illuminate/filesystem/blob/master/FilesystemAdapter.php#L50)

Comment: I had tried to do a composer update previously but I still got the same error.